# How to normalize a 4D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deep-learning

I have a three dimensional numpy array of images ([CIFAR-10 dataset](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html)). The image array shape is like below:

```
a = np.random.rand(32, 32, 3)
```

Before I do any deep learning, I want to normalize the data to get better result. With a 1D array, I know we can do min max normalization like this:

```
v = np.random.rand(6)
(v - v.min())/(v.max() - v.min())

Out[68]:
array([ 0.89502294,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.65069468,  0.63657915,
        0.08932196])
```

However, when it comes to a 3D array, I am totally lost. Specifically, I have the following questions:

1. Along which axis do we take the min and max?
2. How do we implement this with the 3D array?

I appreciate your help!

---

EDIT:
It turns out I need to work with a 4D Numpy array with shape `(202, 32, 32, 3)`, so the first dimension would be the index for the image, and the last 3 dimensions are the actual image. It'll be great if someone can provide me with the code to normalize such a 4D array. Thanks!

---

EDIT 2:
Thanks to @Eric's code below, I've figured it out:

```
x_min = x.min(axis=(1, 2), keepdims=True)
x_max = x.max(axis=(1, 2), keepdims=True)

x = (x - x_min)/(x_max-x_min)
```

Comment: Is your stack 4d (image# x X x Y x RGB) or 3d (image# x X x Y)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you're working with image data of shape `(W, H, 3)`, you should probably normalize over each channel (`axis=2`) separately, as mentioned in the other answer.

You can do this with:

```
# keepdims makes the result shape (1, 1, 3) instead of (3,). This doesn't matter here, but
# would matter if you wanted to normalize over a different axis.
v_min = v.min(axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)
v_max = v.max(axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)
(v - v_min)/(v_max - v_min)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I actually need to work with a 4D array (I've updated my post). Can you please provide further direction?

Comment: I've figured out how to do this thanks to your code!

Comment: @George: Yep, what you have is correct - you're taking the maximum over the x and y (axes 1 and 2) for each image and channel (axes 0 and 3)

Answer (score 4):

1. Along which axis do we take the min and max?

To answer this we probably need more information about your data, but in general, when discussing 3 channel images for example, we would normalize using the per-channel min and max. this means that we would perform the normalization 3 times - once per channel.
Here's an example:

```
    img = numpy.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 10, 3))  # Generating some random numbers
    img = img.astype(numpy.float32)  # converting array of ints to floats
    img_a = img[:, :, 0]
    img_b = img[:, :, 1]
    img_c = img[:, :, 2]  # Extracting single channels from 3 channel image
    # The above code could also be replaced with cv2.split(img) << which will return 3 numpy arrays (using opencv)

    # normalizing per channel data:
    img_a = (img_a - numpy.min(img_a)) / (numpy.max(img_a) - numpy.min(img_a))
    img_b = (img_b - numpy.min(img_b)) / (numpy.max(img_b) - numpy.min(img_b))
    img_c = (img_c - numpy.min(img_c)) / (numpy.max(img_c) - numpy.min(img_c))

    # putting the 3 channels back together:
    img_norm = numpy.empty((10, 10, 3), dtype=numpy.float32)
    img_norm[:, :, 0] = img_a
    img_norm[:, :, 1] = img_b
    img_norm[:, :, 2] = img_c
```

Edit: It just occurred to me that once you have the one channel data (32x32 image for instance) you can simply use:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
img_a_norm = normalize(img_a)
```

2. How do we work with the 3D array?

Well, this is a bit of a big question. If you need functions like array-wise min and max I would use the Numpy versions. Indexing, for instance, is achieved through axis-wide separators - as you can see from my example above. 
Also, please refer to Numpy's documentation of ndarray @ https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html
to learn more. they really have an amazing set of tools for n-dimensional arrays.

Comment: This is wrong way of normalization, you have to subtract min from max. i.e. `img_a = (img_a - numpy.min(img_a)) / (numpy.max(img_a) - numpy.min(img_a))` make sure the paranthesis are correct

Comment: @smttsp you're absolutely right, i mistyped, fixing my original answer. thanks.

Comment: _"we would perform the normalization 3 times - once per channel"_ - right, but this is much better expressed as _"normalize over `axis=-1`"_. No need to repeat your code once for each channel

Comment: `r, g, b = cv2.split(img)` can also be written `r, g, b = np.moveaxis(img, -1, 0)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I actually need to work with a 4D array (I've updated my post). Can you please provide further direction?

Comment: @Eric that method is new to me, nice to know that's possible. George, I see from your second edit that you've figured it out?

Comment: Yep, a lot of the more basic cv2 functionality is better expressed in terms of numpy operations

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches here. You can either decide to normalize over the whole batch of images or normalize per single image. To do that you can either use the mean of a single image or use the mean of the whole batch of images or use a fixed mean from another dataset - e.g. you can use the `ImageNet` mean value.

If you want to do the same as Tensorflow's [`tf.image.per_image_standardization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization) you should normalize per single image with the mean of this image. So you loop through all images and do the normalization for all axes in a single image like this:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# open images
image_1 = Image.open("your_image_1.jpg")
image_2 = Image.open("your_image_2.jpg")
images = [image_1, image_2]
images = np.array(images)
standardized_images = []

# standardize images
for image in images:
    mean = image.mean()
    stddev = image.std()
    adjusted_stddev = max(stddev, 1.0/math.sqrt(image.size))
    standardized_image = (image - mean) / adjusted_stddev
    standardized_images.append(standardized_image)

standardized_images = np.array(standardized_images)
```